# How i make Ubuntu 18.04/20.04 use xorg by default instead of xrandr?

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, xorg, display-resolution, color-depth

I want to change the color depth of a Ubuntu VM installed on a server. Lower color depth reduce the bandwidth (smoother screen) when connecting over SPICE-gtk. With xrandr I can't change the color depth to 16 like with Xorg.

I made a xorg.conf in /etc/X11 with the following code:

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Virtual-screen"
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth 16
        Modes "1600x900" "800x600" "640x480"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

When I use: `Identifier "Virtual-screen"` in the xorg.conf I'm not able to pass the login screen after restarting gdm. But when I use `Identifier "Virtual-0"` I am able to login but nothing changes, the machine is still using xrandr and `$ xwininfo -root | grep Depth` keeps telling me 24.

When I reboot my machine it keeps using xrandr settings too, even after removing ./config/monitors.xml

Same issue with a /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/ config.

Additional information:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1600 x 900, maximum 8192 x 8192
Virtual-0 connected primary 1600x900+0+0 0mm x 0mm
```

I have no other active displays.

What am I doing wrong and how to make it work?

Comment: I thought that xrandr is a runtime thingy on top of xorg, capable of updating / overriding xorg config on the fly. So I would assume that whatever settings xrandr presents as "its" defaults, it took them originally from some form of xorg config. If therefore your defaults are not what you desire, I would assume that your xorg config attempt does not take effect... I too would gladly learn more about this.

Comment: What display manager are you using? What graphic card driver are you using? Are you using Ubuntu Desktop or Server?

Comment: @Serg Libvirt VM (Ubuntu desktop) installed on an Ubuntu server. Driver = qxl